# opening website in pop up with fixed width and height error

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, popup

I have the following webpage which displays a terminal. You type in the bottom bar (e.g. help) and a response is output.

Test input: /unsolvedproblems

If you enter the above, you notice the output includes a hyperlink. I have tried various things to get the link to open not just in a new tab but in a pop up window with a fixed width and height.

The relevant part of the code is here:

```
} else if (input.value === "/unsolvedproblems" || input.value==="unsolvedproblems") {
      matrixEffect();
      clearCommand();
      textArea.innerHTML += "<br><br>--------Greatest unsolved problems--------<br><br>Here is a list of the greatest <a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_unsolved_problems' target=_'blank'><strong><u>unsolved problems</u></strong></a> in the world (check out the ones on Computer Science!)";
```

I have tried:

```
<a href=onclick="window.open'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_unsolved_problems' target=_'blank' 'width=600,height=600'>
```

and a few other options and keep getting errors.

The whole code (trinket is here) https://trinket.io/html/c979638f8e?runMode=autorun

I also tried this, again with errors:

```
     } else if (input.value === "/bye" || input.value==="bye") {
      matrixEffect();
      clearCommand();
      textArea.innerHTML += "<br><br>--------Goodbye!--------<br><br>Have a good day! <a href="https:www.google.com" 
  target="popup" 
  onclick="window.open('https:www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600,scrollbars=no,resizable=no'); return false;">
    Open Link in Popup
</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to open a link in a popup window? If you are then you could try this.

```
<input type="button" value="Open popup" onclick="window.open('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_unsolved_problems','popUpWindow','height=500,width=700,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');">
```

Comment: could you put this in the context of my code please and verify it works? Note it is a CONSOLE window (see trinket link at the end). The code (see whole context) doesn't seem to be working like a usual html page in every instance

Comment: Could you make your question more clear? I'm finding it a bit hard to follow

Comment: i want a hyperlink, as shown in my code, to open as a pop. Your solution doesn't work as I don't want a button and it is a console. If you put the answer in the context I've put it and show that it works I can verify and accept your answer.